# System Shared Preferences

Tags: permissions

I am new to Android. Using shared preferences each application can store key-value pairs and it can be in several modes (private, public read, etc) and the default mode is the private mode because of security issues.

I understand that if an application set the mode to 'public', it would be readable by other apps. But I am wondering if there are any system-wide shared preferences that can be read by all the applications by default? How can I find the list of all readable preferences (of other apps)? Should I enumerate all /data/data/*/shared_prefs/*.xml and see to which one I have access?